# display a different, larger photo on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html

Usually i'm here for help with a JavaScript class that I just started, but this on is for a personal project that I'm working on. I have code (see below) that will increase the size of a photo on mouse-over, and it works fine.

Problem is, I want to not only display a larger image but for one of these I'd like to also display a different image completely on mouse-over (and yes, still at a larger size too!).

This is what I've been working with but can't seem to get it to work correctly (the first image is a "before", and the second is an after Photoshop enhancement with both before/after side by side). Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks...

```
<p><a href="" target="blank"><img class="displayed" src="Images/sheriffcarB4.jpg" width="250" height="150" alt="Photoshop Enhancement" onmouseover= "this.src=Images/sheriffcarcompare.jpg" "this.width=1100;this.height=350;"onmouseout="this.width=250;this.height=150"/></a></p></div>
```

Comment: You seem to be closing a double quote after the name of the image, instead of a semi-colon.

Comment: Thank you, Fareesh. Got it to work with everyones help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
<div>
    <p><a href="" target="blank"><img class="displayed" src="Images/sheriffcarB4.jpg" 
    width="250" height="150" alt="Photoshop Enhancement" onmouseover= "this.src='Images/sheriffcarcompare.jpg';this.width=1100;this.height=350;" onmouseout="this.width=250;this.height=150"/></a>
    </p>
</div>
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jEPwW/1/)

In the Demo wait for a secong over you hover over the image for the image src to change. This happens only because the src is a 3rd party website. It will work perfectly in your case

Comment: Thanks @MarsOne but that didn't seem to work - very similar to what I've been trying, and I'm sure it would work but can't seem to get the exact syntax needed! : )

Comment: Have you checked the demo?

Comment: It is your code itself. I just fixed you syntax errors. Its works for me in the fiddle.

Comment: Yeah, checked out your demo and saw that it worked but I copied the changes to the code above exactly and tried but it doesn't work for me?!? All others work on the page but they're only larger images when moused over - this one needs to be different because it'll show a before/after image...

Comment: Ahh. thats the problem. Let me fix that for you. Try the code now. it should work. WHat error does the console throw?

Comment: I was missing the single quote! Works like a charm, MarsOne, and I don't have to go back and change them all to HTML & add more CSS. Thank you very much, and thanks to all who weighed in with ideas, it's very much appreciated! peace...

Answer (score 5):

You can do this without using javascript at all...  The `:hover` CSS selector is similar to the `onmouseover` javascript event.

```
<style>
   a img.Large { display: none; }

   a:hover img.Small { display: none }
   a:hover img.Large { display: block; }
</style>

<a href="your link">
   <img class="Small" src="Images/sheriffcarB4.jpg" 
      width="250" height="150"
      alt="Photoshop Enhancement" />

   <img class="Large" src="Images/sheriffcarcompare.jpg" 
      width="1100" height="350"
      alt="Photoshop Enhancement" />
</a>
```

Comment: I'm hoping to keep things consistent on the page, but would there be an advantage to using strictly HTML rather than JavaScript in this case? Just wondering, thanks...

Comment: One benefit is that if both images are already rendered as `<img />` tags, then the browser will go ahead and download the large image on page load.  That will prevent any jitter on mouse over because the image will already be loaded.

Comment: Thanks for this information, David. Even though I'm going to stick with the method above so I don't have to change anything else on the page, I'm probably going to use the method you & Gadde referred to going forward since it would help avoid the mouse jitters you referred to.

Answer (score 2):

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WUfbv/)

```
Html
 <a href="#">
  <img class="actul" src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTjlz0eYHrzmEgWQ-xCtzyxIkA6YoZHpG0DnucD1syQXtTLyoZvuQ" width="400" height="300"
  alt="picSmall" />
 <img class="another" src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT7cjWFiYeCohI7xgGzgW60EHd-kEJyG3eNEdJJhnhp7RFT6o6m" width="600" height="350"
  alt="picLarge" />
</a>

Css

a img.another { display: none; }

   a:hover img.actul { display: none }
   a:hover img.another { display: block; }
```

Comment: Thank you, Gadde - I'm guessing that's pretty similar to what @David was trying to convey to me. Question for you as well: is there a benefit to doing it this way over using JavaScript?? I'm trying for consistency and hate to have to change everyone that has already been done! This is the only one needing to be a different image...

Comment: You are using javscipt in your HTML itself. SO it does not make a difference if you use it in a function. CSS is a totally different thing. Performancewise It wont make a huge difference to have js in you html or as a seperate function

Comment: @MarsOne Hay where did i use JavaScript ??